# Defining 3 schemas in MongoDB with different relations (many-to-many, one-to-many...)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have 3 different schemas in my application:

```
userSchema, questionSchema, listingSchema
```

The relationship between the three is as follows:
Each **listing** has many questions associated with it (same ones for each listing).
Each **user** *can answer* many questions in several listings.
Each **question** is answered by many users in many listings.

I am trying to wrap my head around defining a correct relationship between those schemas (mainly because of problems like "user with `_id = 100` answered a question with `_id = 5` in a listing with `_id = 3` , how do I update all these in  the most efficient way?).

So far I have defined:

questionSchema:

```
var questionSchema = new Schema({
    description:  String
});
```

userSchema:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({

    local            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
        name         : String
    },
    ApartmentsAndQuestions: [{
        apartmentID: String,
        questionID: [String] /* one apartment -> multiple questions */
    }]
});
```

And listingSchema:

```
var listingSchema = new Schema({
     street          : String,
    buildingNumber  : Number,
    apartmentNumber : Number,
    type            : String,
    floor           : Number,
    outOfFloors     : Number,
    numberOfRooms   : Number,
    size            : Number,
    renovated       : Boolean,
    elevator        : Boolean,
    airConditioning : Boolean,
    balcony         : Boolean,
    price           : Number,
    description     : String,
    flagCount       : Number,
    pictures        : [imageSchema]
    owner           : [userSchema]

    UsersAndQuestions: [{
            userID: String,
            questionID: [String] /* one user -> multiple questions asked possible */
    }]
});
```

**Question:** How do I do it well in my NoSQL database? Do my definitions make sense? Is there a better way to describe the relations between those schemas?

Any help will be  **greatly**  appreciated!

Comment: You need to ask a specific question about a problem. "Does this make sense" isn't a real question but rather asking for verification.

Comment: I think it is a valid question to ask if my design makes sense or if there is something better that i'm unaware of or didn't implement correctly

Comment: Have you at least tried if it's working? If it's working and does the thing you designed it to do - it makes sens. If it doesn't work, then why - are there any errors or you have some kind of problems? What are those problems? I don't see any of that information. Put some efforts before asking questions, please.

Comment: few questions: (1) It sounds like every listing has the same questions ("same ones for each listing"), is that correct? If so, whats the point of multiple listings? (2) Whats your expected outcome if one users answers the same question on 2 different listings?

Comment: @DavidGrinberg 1. Yes, every listing does have the same set of questions. And there are many listing (all different from each other) 2. When a user answers a question in a listing, he can no longer be asked the *same* question in the *same* listing. But he *can* be asked the *same* question in a *different* listing. Sounds legit? (:

Comment: @Idos I'm not clear what the point of listings is though if they all have the same questions. How are they different?

Comment: @David a listing is of an apartment, which has different apartment description, different pictures, different owner etc... They are all unique. The questions they share are the same, but I have to know when user A answers question B in listing C..

Comment: @Idos, are you able to use MongoDB 3.2 which add [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) which is, basically, a LEFT JOIN?

Comment: @ConstantinGuay what do you mean by "able" ? and how would it answer my question?

Comment: @Idos I mean able, because not everyone can upgrade a production version easily per example :) And it would help because 3.2 add the possibility, with $lookup, to LEFT JOIN another collection. And then, depending of how many "many" you have, it can not harm to use it, instead of embedding. But be careful, it should not be used for too much. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34119446/evaluating-mongodb-aggregation-query-complexity-cost-of-lookup) for more information about $lookup performance

Comment: @ConstantinGuay if you show me what you mean by "add" then of course I can. my app is small and for teaching purposes (no more than 50 of each schema will be added...) :)

Comment: @Idos I've add an example as answer. Please tell me if you need more explanation, or if I misunderstand your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to define your schemas as follows:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local            : {
        email        : String,
            password     : String,
            name             : String
    },
    /* every entry in the array is an apartment ID and the questionsIDs (array) of the questions that the user ALREADY answered in that *specific* apartment */
    ApartmentsAndQuestions: [{
        apartmentID : String,
        questionsIDs: [String]
    }]
});
```

And:

```
var listingSchema = new Schema({
     street          : String,
     buildingNumber  : Number,
     apartmentNumber : Number,
     type            : String,
     floor           : Number,
     outOfFloors     : Number,
     numberOfRooms   : Number,
     size            : Number,
     renovated       : Boolean,
     elevator        : Boolean,
     airConditioning : Boolean,
     balcony         : Boolean,
     price           : Number,
     description     : String,
     flagCount       : Number,
     ownerID         : String,
     /* every entry in the array is a userID and the questionsIDs (array) of the questions that the user ALREADY answered in that *specific* apartment */
     UsersAndQuestions: [{
        userID: String,
        questionID: [String]
    }],
    /* every image has a count of how many times the users answered YES or NO on it */
    imagesAndCount: [{
        imageID: String,
        count: Number
    }]
});
```

Then you can basically do something in the lines of:

```
var someuser = db.users.find()[2] // get some user
```

`someuser._id` >>> which returns some `ObjectId("56472a83bd9fa764158d0cb6")`
Then: `db.users.find({_id: ObjectId("56472a83bd9fa764158d0cb6")}) >>> which will return someuser (with all the fields that are defined in the User schema)`

Then: `db.listings.insert({"street" : "SomeStreet", "buildingNumber" : 33, "apartmentNumber" : 63, "beds": 3, "owner" : "56472a83bd9fa764158d0cb6"})`

And the listing will look like this:
Now the listing looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "566c220abcda51a9eef08576"
    },
    "street": "SomeStreet",
    "buildingNumber": 33,
    "apartmentNumber": 63,
    "beds": 3,
    "owner": "56472a83bd9fa764158d0cb6"
}
```

Comment: That looks really good! And the example really helped me understand! Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

**MongoDB 3.2+ solution**

Add mentionned in comments, you can use new [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) to avoid embedding lot of data. It's like a SQL LEFT JOIN:

Let's add some data, matching yours:

```
db.questionSchema.insert({ _id: 1, description: "My description 1" });
db.questionSchema.insert({ _id: 2, description: "My description 2" });
db.questionSchema.insert({ _id: 3, description: "My description 3" });
db.questionSchema.insert({ _id: 4, description: "My description 4" });

db.userSchema.insert({ _id: 1, email: "my@email1.com", ApartmentsAndQuestions: [] });
db.userSchema.insert({ _id: 2, email: "my@email2.com", ApartmentsAndQuestions: [] });

db.listingSchema.insert({ _id: "A", UsersAndQuestions: [] })
db.listingSchema.insert({ _id: "B", UsersAndQuestions: [] })

// Add some questions
db.userSchema.update({ _id: 1 }, { $addToSet: { ApartmentsAndQuestions: { apartment_id: 1, question_id: [1] } } })
db.userSchema.update({ _id: 1, "ApartmentsAndQuestions.apartment_id": 1 }, { $addToSet: { "ApartmentsAndQuestions.$.question_id": 3 } })

db.userSchema.update({ _id: 2 }, { $addToSet: { ApartmentsAndQuestions: { apartment_id: 2, question_id: [1,2] } } })
db.userSchema.update({ _id: 2, "ApartmentsAndQuestions.apartment_id": 2 }, { $addToSet: { "ApartmentsAndQuestions.$.question_id": 4 } })

db.listingSchema.update({ _id: "A" }, { $addToSet: { UsersAndQuestions: { user_id: 1, question_id: [1] } } })
```

With a regular find, here is what you get:

```
test> db.listingSchema.find()
{
  "_id": "B",
  "UsersAndQuestions": [ ]
}
{
  "_id": "A",
  "UsersAndQuestions": [
    {
      "user_id": 1,
      "question_id": [
        1
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, let's $lookup:

```
db.listingSchema.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$UsersAndQuestions"
    }
    ,{
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "userSchema",
            localField: "UsersAndQuestions.user_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "fetched_user"
        }
    }
    ,{
        $unwind: "$UsersAndQuestions.question_id"
    }
    ,{
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "questionSchema",
            localField: "UsersAndQuestions.question_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "fetched_question"
        }
    }
])
```

You get:

```
{
  "waitedMS": NumberLong("0"),
  "result": [
    {
      "_id": "A",
      "UsersAndQuestions": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "question_id": 1
      },
      "fetched_user": [
        {
          "_id": 1,
          "email": "my@email1.com",
          "ApartmentsAndQuestions": [
            {
              "apartment_id": 1,
              "question_id": [
                1,
                3
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "fetched_question": [
        {
          "_id": 1,
          "description": "My description 1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "ok": 1
}
```

Then, you could $unwind `ApartmentsAndQuestions.questions_id` too and $lookup questions data too. It's up to you.

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate the effort, but I didn't even ask about all this. I know how to use find() or other db functions... I asked about the Schemas relations and the best way to define each according to my needs...Upvoted any way