# Evaluating MongoDB aggregation query complexity: cost of $lookup

Tags: algorithm, mongodb, join, aggregation-framework

I'm evaluating the computational cost of my algorithm that involves some MongoDB aggregation queries, so I'm trying to figure out the costs of the various operators I use, then the cost of the whole query will be just the sum of all of them as they're applied in cascade.

I came up saying that the cost of $project, $match and $unwind is O(n), with n being the number of documents in the collection, as I don't have any index so I need to scan all the documents.

Now my question is: what about the cost of the new $lookup operator? It performs a left join over two collections, so my first guess it that it kinda computes the cartesian product of the two collections, hence the cost should be something like O(n * m), where m is the size of the second collection. Am I right? Does MongoDB do something more efficient? Do you have any reference about this topic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) is effectively an `$in` query against the referenced collection, where the value of `$in` is the set of `localField` values from the pipeline to lookup.

If the `foreignField` is indexed, that query's complexity is O(log(n)). If the `foreignField` isn't indexed, the query's complexity is O(n).

Comment: In my case foreignField is not indexed, so it is O(n) wrt the local collection.. but what about the foreign collection? Shouldn't we take into account also its size?

Comment: It's O(n) wrt to the _foreign_ collection. Think of the query as looping through the entire foreign collection, and for each of those docs checking to see if it's needed for one of the lookups.

Comment: Aaaah!! Ok!! Wow, I expected worse perfomances! Thanks!! :) :)